# Jackson CSV mapper doesn't insert CSV file content correctly (header doesn't match values)?

Tags: java, csv, jackson

I have a CSV file `pets.csv`:

```
NUMBER,NAME,TYPE
1,Jack,Dog
2,Russel,Cat
3,Great,Mouse
```

I have a custom class for each of the `pets`:

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "NUMBER", "NAME", "TYPE" })
public class Pet {

    public String number;
    public String name;
    public String type;
}
```

Then inside `main` class I wish to fetch data from `pets.csv` into `List<Pet>`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<Pet> pets = readFile(Path.of("pets.csv"));
    pets.forEach(pet -> System.out.println(pet.name));
}

public static List<Pet> readFile(Path csvFile) throws IOException {
    try(MappingIterator<Pet> petIter = new CsvMapper()
            .readerWithTypedSchemaFor(Pet.class).readValues(csvFile.toFile())) {
        return petIter.readAll();
    }
}
```

However instead of having an output of:

```
NAME
Jack
Russel
Great
```

I got:

```
NUMBER
1
2
3
```

What am I doing wrong? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recreated and works perfectly if:

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "number", "name", "type" })
public class Pet {

    public String number;
    public String name;
    public String type;
}
```

So, lowercase them. Hope this helps :)